# Javascript for() loop w/ object declaration and IN reserved word - just looking for some clarification

Tags: javascript, json, object, for-loop

I am working an a basic learning script below. My main question is in the for() declaration what is the 'IN' reserved word and how does the starName relate to it because it is not defined anywhere earlier on the page.

I am trying to understand how the for() loop is "thinking" with that **starName in star** statement.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var star = {};

star["Polaris"] = new Object;
star["Mizar"] = new Object;
star["Aldebaran"] = new Object;
star["Rigel"] = new Object;

star["Polaris"].constellation = "Ursa Minor";
star["Mizar"].constellation = "Ursa Major";
star["Aldebaran"].constellation = "Taurus";
star["Rigel"].constellation = "Orion";

</script>
</head>
<body id="mainbody">

<script type="text/javascript">
for (starName in star) {
var para = document.createElement('p');
para.id = starName;
para.appendChild(document.createTextNode(starName +
": " + star[starName].constellation));
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(para);
}
</script>

<!-- output below -->

<p id="Polaris">Polaris: Ursa Minor</p>
<p id="Mizar">Mizar: Ursa Major</p>
<p id="Aldebaran">Aldebaran: Taurus</p>
<p id="Rigel">Rigel: Orion</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `for ... in` syntax enumerates all *enumerable* properties of an object.

`starName` will be a string that represents the name of the property. You can that access that property (and do plenty of other things) like that:

```
var p = star[starName];
```

Now there are a couple things you should be aware of when using the `for ... in` syntax:

Make use of [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) to safeguard against properties added higher in the prototype chain.

```
Object.prototype.allObjectWillInheritThis = 1;

/// ...

for (var starName in star) {
    if (star.hasOwnProperty(starName)) {

        // Do your thing
    }
}
```

Filter out functions. Chances are you are not interested in function but in properties.

```
for (var starName in star) {
    if (star.hasOwnProperty(starName) &&
        typeof star[starName] !== 'function') {

        // Do your thing
    }
}
```

Comment: Bryan, thanks for the detailed description and tips for usage.

Comment: Also, `starName` is not declared anywhere, so it becomes a property of the global object (i.e. effectively a global variable). Better to declare it with `var`, which could be in the `for...in`: `for (var starName in in star) {...}`

Comment: Very good observation. Edited my answer. I'm so used to hoisting `var` declaration in JavaScript... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help: `for(newVariable in existingVariable)`;

The for-loop construct creates a new variable that you can use as the current value in your loop.  The second value is a variable you want to loop on.

As pointed out by Bryan, the for-in construct only loops on enumerable properties.  If you want to check if something is enumerable, you can call `.propertyIsEnumerable(0)` on it.

Comment: Levi, that pretty much exactly answers my question. My script is working. I tried to do search for Javascript "in" in google - that was fruitless. So the IN is in fact assigning a value to the newVariable is what I understand now.

Comment: @OldWest, correct.  The value being assigned is the current property in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

How it works, is star is an array (or object) with multiple values.  Imagine an array with numbers 1 to 10.

The `in` keyword iterates through the array and assigns the value to starName.  So the array with numbers 1 to 10 will iterate 10 times, and each time starName will become the next value.

The order is based on the index of the array (or object)

Comment: Good practice dictates that arrays should be iterated with a regular for loop not a for / in. There is no defined order for the properties of an object.

Answer (score 0):

This construction

```
for(var key in collection) { ... }
```

allows to iterate over enumerable keys in JS collections (objects/maps and arrays).
On each iteration `key` will get new key value contained in the collection.

Note #1: `for(...in...)` has a "cool" feature of iterating not only through keys defined on objects themselves but also in their prototypes.

Note #2: Key variable should have 'var' keyword in front of it in order this loop to work effectively. Without 'var' the 'key' variable will be created in global namespace.